# ¿Como leer correos POP3 desde C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lo que deseo hacer, es leer un tipo de archivo adjunto, por ejemplo los que son .pdf, de aquellos correos que no han sido leídos. Para comenzar, estaba probando con un simple ejemplo para leer, pero me dice el siguiente mensaje:

Server did not accept user credentials

Y estoy seguro que el nombre de usuario y contraseña son correctos.

El ejemplo simple con el que estaba probando sería este (Es una clase que hice):

```
class ConnectPop3
{             
    private string username = "micorreo@gmail.com";

    private string password = "miclave";

    private int port = 995;

    private string hostname = "pop.gmail.com";

    private bool useSsl = true;

    public List<Message> getMensajes()
    {
        try
        {

            // El cliente se desconecta al terminar el using
            using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
            {
                // conectamos al servidor
                client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);

                // Autentificación
                client.Authenticate(username, password, OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

                // Obtenemos los Uids mensajes
                List<string> uids = client.GetMessageUids();

                // creamos instancia de mensajes
                List<Message> lstMessages = new List<Message>();

                // Recorremos para comparar
                for (int i = 0; i < uids.Count; i++)
                {
                    //obtenemos el uid actual, es él id del mensaje
                    string currentUidOnServer = uids[i];

                    //por medio del uid obtenemos el mensaje con el siguiente metodo
                    Message oMessage = client.GetMessage(i + 1);

                    //agregamos el mensaje a la lista que regresa el metodo
                    lstMessages.Add(oMessage);

                }

                // regresamos la lista
                return lstMessages;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //si ocurre una excepción regresamos null, es importante que cachen las excepciones, yo
            //lo hice general por modo de ejemplo
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Y del index lo llamo así:

```
protected void LeerCorreo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       ConnectPop3 oCP3 = new ConnectPop3();

        //invocamos el metodo para obtener mensajes
        List<OpenPop.Mime.Message> lstMensajes = oCP3.getMensajes();

        //recorremos y mostramos el asunto
        foreach (OpenPop.Mime.Message oMensaje in lstMensajes)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(oMensaje.Headers.Subject);
            MessageBox.Show(oMensaje.Headers.Subject);
        }
   }
```

Me gustaría saber como solucionar el mensaje Server did not accept user credentials. Después me gustaría poder leer los correo que no han sido leídos en la bandeja de entrada, pero de esos corros, solo los adjuntos con un formato especifico.

Después probé de esta forma:
Actualmente lo estoy probando así:

```
       ImapClient ic = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", "micorreo@gmail.com", "miclave",
        AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true);                
        // Select a mailbox. Case-insensitive
        ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
        Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount());             
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ic.GetMessageCount().ToString());

        MailMessage[] mm = ic.GetMessages(0, 10);
        foreach (MailMessage m in mm)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Subject);
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(m.Subject);
        }
        // Probably wiser to use a using statement
        ic.Dispose();
```

pero necesito leer los que no han sido leídos del inbox, pero en este caso me los lee todos.

Comment: Yo te recomendaría abandonar POP3 y utilizar IMAP. El servidor POP de Gmail es conocido por funcionar de formas extrañas en ocasiones. De todas maneras, debes habilitar el servidor pop en tu cuenta de gmail para poder utilizarlo.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta @Pikoh, pero me gustaría si fuera posible obtener un ejemplo de usar con IMAP, te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: He editado mi respuesta para obtener todos los correos no leidos y luego ir obteniendo los adjuntos. Espero que sea lo que querias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para leer los correos de Gmail utilizando Imap, yo usaría la libreria AE.Net.Mail (la tienes disponible en NuGet) y el codigo sería algo asi:

```
AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient ic = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", "user@gmail.com", "pass",
AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true);
ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount());
```

Ten en cuenta que para que funcione, deberas tener abierto el puerto 993.

**Edit**
El codigo siguiente obtiene los id's de los correos no leidos y luego obtiene los nombres de archivo de los adjuntos:

```
List<string> ids = new List<string>();
List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage> mails = new List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage>();

using (var imap = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", username, password, AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true)) 
{
    var msgs = imap.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Unseen());
    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++) {
        string msgId = msgs[i].Uid;
        ids.Add(msgId);            
    }

    foreach (string id in ids)
    {
        mails.Add(imap.GetMessage(id, headersonly: false));
    }
}

foreach(var msg in mails)
{
    foreach (var att in msg.Attachments) 
    {
        string fName;
        fName = att.Filename;
    }
}
```

Espero que este ejemplo te ayude.

Comment: Si esos son tus datos reales,elimina este comentario inmediatamente @danilo

Comment: Por otro lado si,tiene que ser true. Editado. Y como te explico,comprueba que el puerto 993 sea alcanzable

Comment: @danilo si te muestra ese numero,es que has conseguido acceder correctamente. El numero que ves son los mensajes que tienes en tu carpeta inbox

Comment: con tu ayuda puse una forma de leerlos, pero deseo ver los que no han sido abiertos o leídos. Y además, si lleva un archivo adjunto de tipo xml

Comment: Pero en este caso @Pikoh, donde iría m.Flags.HasFlags(Flag.Unseen), ya que no tendría sentido que estuviese dentro del for ya que estaría recorriendo todos los mensajes, y como podría ver el nombre de los archivos adjuntos?

Comment: Pues si,tendria que estar dentro del for. Tienes que ir mirando uno a uno si ha sido leido. En cuanto a los adjuntos,de memoria no te se decir,pero mira la documentacion de la libreria y si no mañana desde el trabajo te digo.

Comment: vale @Pikoh.  espero que haya solución