# Descargar Adjuntos en Correo de Gmail

Tags: c#, .net

Alguien me podria ayudar con esto, he estado buscando como hacerlo pero algunos blogs suben los codigos incompletos o con librerias desconocidas lo que necesito es leer un correo con un asunto en gmail y descargar el adjunto que llega en el correo, la tarea ya la hice con php pero lo quisiera hacer en c#

Gracias por su ayuda quedo atento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrias agregar el codigo que tienes, en que estas detenido,  tu pregunta es muy amplia.

Comment: Gracias ya leo el correo no he conseguido encontrar el codigo para descargar el adjunto

Comment: Plantea bien tu pregunta añade el código pera lograr entender bien como ayudarte .

Comment: ok estoy intentando usar esto de otra pregunta formulada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/31123/como-leer-correos-pop3-desde-c

Comment: ya añadi el codigo.. eso es lo unico que tengo hasta ahora, quiero buscar el ultimo correo con un asunto especifico y descargar el adjunto que viene en el

Comment: te recomiendo que uses las api's de google te ahorran bastante trabajo y lo que buscas lo implementas rapidamente no mas de 50 lineas de codigo. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

Comment: miguel gracias por tu comentario mire el link que mandaste pero realmente no entiendo como usarlo para lo que quiero

Comment: @Daniel agregue una respuesta revisala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal Daniel por falta de tiempo solo te dare la guia para que lo resuelvas por tu cuenta, despues te ayudo a afinar la solucion,

Como lo mencione en un comentario te recomiendo usar el api de gmail para net

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#prerequisites

ahora para que no escribas mucho codigo descarga la aplicacion:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/To-Read-Gmail-Inbox-fom-4132202a

cuando abras la aplicacion en Visual Studio notaras que falta el archivo clien_secret.json  //es un archivo particular por usuario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para obtener ese archivo en tu navegador entra a tu cuenta de gmail
despues pega la ruta:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet#prerequisites
presiona el boton "Enable the gmail api"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
te descargara el archivo json ese archivo copia y pega en la carpeta ConsoleApp1 renombralo con "client_secret.json" refresca el proyecto en Visula studio y podras ver el archivo sin problemas.

--
En el archivo program.cs notaras las lineas

```
 var inboxlistRequest = service.Users.Messages.List("tucorreo@gmail.com");
```

despues

```
 var emailInfoRequest = service.Users.Messages.Get("tucorreo@gmail.com", email.Id);
```

como es obvio sustituye el texto tu correo por tu gmail id tu cuenta pues.

f5 o corre la solucion, aqui abre una ventana de navegador solicitando los permisos de acceso. Te generara otro archivo y lo guardara en tus documentos carpeta  .credentials,
deten la aplicacion y ejecutala nuevamente

Listo eso es todo :

en la parte donde esta la condicion aqui es donde estan los **Archivos Adjuntos**:

```
  if (p.MimeType == "text/html")
                                    {
```

deberas agregar otra para tus imagenes

```
 if (p.MimeType == "image/jpeg")
                                {
```

despues de la llave tendras que guardar lostextos, la imagen, y agregaras condiciones para otro tipo de archivos.

En caso de que no puedas guardar el adjunto envias otro comentario,

saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

```
using AE.Net.Mail;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Descargar_Correo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //borrar archivo anterior con el mismo nombre
                string path = 
            System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(Path.GetFileName("~/archivo para borrar"));
                File.Delete(path);
                string msgId ="";
                using (var ic = new AE.Net.Mail.ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 
        "micorreo", "micontraseña", AE.Net.Mail.AuthMethods.Login, 993, true))
            {
                ic.SelectMailbox("INBOX");
                Console.WriteLine(ic.GetMessageCount());
                List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage> mails = new 
           List<AE.Net.Mail.MailMessage>();
                var msgs = ic.SearchMessages(SearchCondition.Subject("asunto que 
        buscar"));

                for (int i = msgs.Length-1; i >= 0;)
                {
                     msgId = msgs[i].Value.Uid;
                    break;              
                }
                mails.Add(ic.GetMessage(msgId, headersonly: false));
                foreach (var msg in mails)
                {
                    foreach (var att in msg.Attachments)
                    {
                        string fName;
                        fName = att.Filename;
                        att.Save(@"ruta para guardar"+fName+"");
                    }
                }
            }     
        }
              catch (Exception ex)
            {
            this.Close();
            throw;
            }
              this.Close();
           }
       }        
    }
```

Comment: lo hice de esta manera